# How can I use STM32 blue pill with external power source (like battery); which pin exactly?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

- How can I use stm32 blue pill with external power source (like
  battery)?
- Which pin exactly? What is the low voltage for working?

[image: stm32 blue pill]

Comment: You need regulated 3.3 or 5v.  With limited knowledge, your best bet it to get an inexpensive USB power bank and use it to power the USB port.

Comment: but when i finish programming with cable usb how can use it with external power and wich pin i give it voltage

Comment: You need to read a manual which explains how to use a product you bought. This is no exception to any other product.

Comment: Do they really call this "the blue pill'???    That's hilarious.  Bet its a rather stiff little board.

Comment: When you finish programming, you can use the USB port on a power bank to power the board.  You can also cut a USB cable and route the red to the 5V pin and black to ground.  Do not apply power to the 5V input while a USB connector is in use (computer damage is unlikely but possible).  The safest way is to just use the USB port for programming and power.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct: you should always refer to the manual for any product you buy. If you aren't provided a manual, the manufacturer web site may have it. As a general rule, if you can't obtain a datasheet or manual, you should look at other products or vendors.

In any case, an internet search for "STM32 blue pill pinout" yields various images that show slightly more detail for the pins:

[image: Bluepill Pinout]

<sup>[Source](https://revspace.nl/STM32)</sup>

***I make no guarantees that this pinout matches the specific item you have. There could be revisions or different models. For example, the tactile switch differs here from the image you posted.***